# When the image of my slideshow changes, the browser jumps to the top of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slideshow

I have seen a couple other people that had this same question (one already on StackOverflow) but have not found a solution that works for my site. Many solutions included poor code, but my site is not poorly coded. I have tripple checked all the lines of code related to this issue and can't figure this out. I am fairly new to jquery and haven't been developing long, but this should be a relatively simple fix compared to some of the other issues I've resolved.

Please feel free to visit my website at www.blingin-it.com and inspect my code to see what I'm talking about. The website is still in the development stage so there are many dead links, but if you click on the 'necklaces tile' (on the home page), click on the only item listed, and then scroll down, you'll notice that when you change from the first image to the second, and so on, the page keeps jumping to the top when you click the 'next' or 'previous' buttons.

If anyone knows a solution to this or could easily find would, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“visit my website at www.blingin-it.com and inspect my code”_ – nope; instead, you please go and read [ask].

Comment: My problem could have been with a variety of elements on my page, and I wasn't about to paste three pages of code into my question. It just doesn't make sense to do that when _anyone_ that knows what they're doing can just as easily go to the website and click on view source code! I looked over the link you posted and, as far as I can tell, did ask my question the proper way, so I really don't know what you're talking about. Linking to a website if someone wants to inspect the actual code, isn't discouraged, & makes a lot more sense than pasting several pages without syntax highlighting!

Comment: You are supposed to include code inside your question, because otherwise this question will likely be useless to people finding it later on, if you fix the issue in your external site, and the problem is not reproducible any more. And of course no one wants to read endless pages of code – which is why it is also your responsibility to try and narrow down the problem beforehand, and produce a minimal example (as the page linked to explicitly explains).

Comment: My point is you shouldn't be rude about it! I'm new to this site and haven't created enough questions yet, or modified any, to see the general post format as they differ from site to site. I also had no idea where in my page the problem was, or I would have pasted that section in the question. Anyone reading this in the future would only need to hear the symptoms and see the answer to understand how to fix it. The original source code in this case is borderline irrelevant. The person that answered the question probably knew the solution without even looking at my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation links point to "#". Linking to a "#" will always bring you to the top of the page.

Culprit:

```
<a class="control_next" href="#">>></a>
<a class="control_prev" href="#"><</a>
```